# Typescript pass function as argument

Tags: angular, typescript

```
  connectWebSocket() {
    const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/websocket');
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    const _this = this;
    this.stompClient.connect({ "Authorization" : "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("Authorization")}, function (frame) {
      _this.stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/notification',function (message) {
        const body = JSON.parse(message.body);
          console.log(body)
      });
    });
  }
```

This is how i connect to websocket curently, but i would like to achieve smthing like this

```
  connectWebSocket(func:Function) {
    const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/websocket');
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    const _this = this;
    this.stompClient.connect({ "Authorization" : "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("Authorization")}, function (frame) {
      _this.stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/notification',func());
    });
  }
```

and then calling it like this

```
  notificationWS(hello){
    const body = JSON.parse(hello.body);
    if(body.notificationType==="FOLLOW"){
      console.log(body)
    }
  }

this.apiService.connectWebSocket(this.notificationWS.bind(this));
```

so i want to pass function as parameter to ws function, but message is null

Comment: I think you have the mentality of React component classes. Can you please try to pass the function like this: this.apiService.connectWebSocket(this.notificationWS);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that in `_this.stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/notification',func());` it expects a function as a second parameter. Instead you already call the function with `func()` and pass the return value.

Try this instead (`func` instead of `func()`):

```js
  connectWebSocket(func:Function) {
    const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/websocket');
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    const _this = this;
    this.stompClient.connect({ "Authorization" : "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("Authorization")}, function (frame) {
      _this.stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/notification',func);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when using `this.notificationWS.bind(this)` the function is executed and it's return value is passed to `connectWebSocket`. To access the pointer to your function try this:

```
this.apiService.connectWebSocket(this.notificationWS.bind);
```

If you need to pass a context a second parameter can be introduced like this

```
  connectWebSocket(func:Function, context: unknown) {
    const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/websocket');
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    const _this = this;
    this.stompClient.connect({ "Authorization" : "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("Authorization")}, function (frame) {
      _this.stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/notification',func(context));
    });
  }

// Call it like this
this.apiService.connectWebSocket(this.notificationWS.bind, this);
```

Comment: No, I'm pretty convinced that `this.notificationWS.bind(this)` does not execute the function, but `func()` does. For an example, take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9hqLwxe/), the result of `foo.bind(window)` is a function.